# Desktop is empty after installation/first logon

Tags: boot

I'm new with linux so I do not know a lot about it. I was just trying to Intall Ubuntu 14.04 on mu DELL DIMENSION E521. The installation worked perfectly fine.. no errors... After the computer rebooted for the first time I got up to the logon screen everything seemed to be normal at that point but after entering my credentials a got to an empty desktop... and nothing else happened.. No icons, no menus, just the mouse pointer and the purple backgroud. I tried several times reinstalling it but I keep getting this empty desktop... any ideas what I should do?

Comment: No idea, but a first step would be to find the original checksum for the iso/image you downloaded or obtained and compare it to the checksum of the image image you have. If they're not the same, get another iso and start over. If they are the same, that's more complicated ...